# How to implement background call pop up UI

Tags: react-native, expo

Can someone please give a guide on how to setup call UI pop up notification? I am building an app with expo where users can make a video call. I Want to implement call notification if the app is in background. I saw many articles about using CallKeep in react native but cannot still get it working. Am using react-native-Webrtc for the video call. can someone please help me with in depth configuration of Callkeep on Expo for both Android and IOS. or any other library I can use just like callKeep. Thanks.

I trie call keep in EAS Build but no luck

Desired Results:
[image]

[image]

Comment: it's been a year, i am searching for this feature in react-native but no lucky